# JSON-LD: Assign custom URIs to blank nodes within context

Tags: json-ld, graphdb, blank-nodes

I'm trying to convert a very large JSON file to JSON-LD. When I import the example code below into GraphDB, `db:metadata` becomes a property/predicate connecting each `GeneSet:setX` node with an automatically created blank node `_:bX` (gray in figure), from which the properties `set_name` and `set_id` then point to their corresponding values.

[image: Linked data example]

```
{
    "@context":{
        "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
        "db": "http://example.com/setDB#",
        "_id": "@id",
        "GeneSet": {"@id": "db:GeneSet"},
        "data": {"@id": "db:metadata"},
        "set_name": {
            "@id": "db:set_name",
            "@type": "xsd:string"
        },
        "set_id": {
            "@id": "db:set_id",
            "@type": "xsd:string"
        }
    },
    "@graph": [
        {
        "_id": "GeneSet:set1",
        "data": {
            "set_name": "set1",
            "set_id": "M123"}},
        {
        "_id": "GeneSet:set2",
        "data": {
            "set_name": "set2",
            "set_id": "M456"}},
        {
        "_id": "GeneSet:set3",
        "data": {
            "set_name": "set3",
            "set_id": "M789"}
        }]
}
```

I would like to convert these blank nodes into actual URIs, preferably with the unique form `db:setX/data`, but the more generic `db:data` could also work. I know I can achieve the former by adding `"@id": "db:data/setX"` within the curly brackets of each `"data": {...}` definition, but since my complete data has over 100,000 of these GeneSets I would like to achieve this by simply modifying the `@context`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort of "templated" ID generation your after is (deliberately) not possible via the JSON-LD `@context` mechanism. The `@context` is for mapping tree data into graph data, not transforming it.

Consequently, looking into injecting those ID values programmatically into the JSON-LD before you process it is one option.

You might also want to ask on the [JSON-LD WG's mailing list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-json-ld-wg/) to get further options.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I suspected that was the case, but since I'm new to JSON-LD I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing something. I ended up correcting the graph structure after importing it into GraphDB. Will be accepting your answer within the next couple of days.

Comment: Yeah. It's a common wish that the `@context` be more "magical" than it is. :) There have been ongoing discussions about exploring the transformation use case more deeply, so asking on the mailing list might get you some new ideas on the topic.